# How, if at all, can a companion app produce passes with different logos and logo text?

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

I'm working on an app that will distribute coupon passes for different stores (e.g. Company A, Company B, Company C, etc.). Since the passes will be for different stores/companies, each pass would ideally use the respective store's logo and logo text instead of my app's logo and logo text.

**How, if at all, can my app distribute passes with different logos and logo text?**

Also, is there a limit on how many different passes I can distribute via the app?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The logo and text used on a Passbook pass are not related to the certificate supplied by Apple used to sign the pass, or the `passTypeIdentifier` registered with Apple. For each different company, just use a different `logo.png`, `icon.png`, `logo@2x.png`, and so forth.

The only parts of the coupon visible to the user are specified in the content of the pass as you create it.

We've used a single Passbook type for order statuses for a white-label tee shirt website, and the appropriate label branding is inserted depending on which site the product was ordered through.

You could also use localization, although it would be a slight abuse of the feature. Each company could have a different `.lproj` with their own strings and images. Check the PassKit Programming Guide ("Localizing a Pass" section) for details.

Comment: I just noticed that while the passes will appear different in Passbook itself, they do get grouped together in Notification Center under one of the names/icons.

However, you can register multiple passTypeIdentifiers with Apple using the same Certificate Signing Request, Private key, etc., so switching between them is straightforward. It's tedious to have to add a certificate for each one, but then they should appear separately in Passbook and Notification Center.

I'm not aware of a limit on the number of registrations. I just did six using the same CSR.

Comment: There's no limit, although Apple do refer in the iOS Developer Agreement to allowing a 'Reasonable Amount'.

Answer (score 2):

Your Passes should not be generated within the App itself, instead they should be generated on a server and then downloaded into the App (or downloaded direct to Passbook, then accessed from the App).

This is because in order to generate and sign a pass on a device, the passTypeIdentifier certificate and the private would need to be embedded in the App which presents a security risk.

[This App](http://lowrxcard.com) uses a third party [Pass Creation service](http://create.passkit.com) to generate the Pass off the device then pull it in through an API.  Using this service you could in theory design and generate any number of passes, using any number of pass certificates, provided you have given permission for your App to access each certificate.

I can't see how the localisation hack @gid suggests would not work since the .lproj content will only ever override the pass defaults when the user's device locale matches the .lproj locale.

Disclaimer: I co-founded PassKit, but the need to generate and sign passes off the device (and show an example of ho it can be done) is the main point I wanted to get across in this answer